# How to activate registration button after all fields are true

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This is the case where I check if fields are true or false

```
function textoEnP(){
var idInput2 = $(this).attr("id");

switch(idInput2){
    case "nombre":
    {
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("No puede estar vacio");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            nombreValido = false;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            nombreValido = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    case "apellido":
    {
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("No puede estar vacio");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            apellidoValido = false;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            apellidoValido = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    case "edad":
    {
        if(isNaN($(this).val())){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe ingresar solo numeros");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            edadValida = false;
        }else if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("No puede estar vacio");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            edadValida = false;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            edadValida = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    case "mail":
    {
        if($(this).val().length < 9 && isNaN($(this).val())){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe usar un formato valido");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            mailValido = false;
        }else if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("No puede estar vacio");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            mailValido = false;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            mailValido = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    case "contraseña":
    {
        password = $(this).val();
        if($(this).val().length < 9){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe tener más de 8 caracteres");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            contraseñaValida = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    case "repetir_contraseña":
    {
        if($(this).val() !== password){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe coincidir con su contraseña");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            repContraseñaValida = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    if($("#checkbox_legales").is(":checked")){
    checkbox_legalesValido = true;
}else{
    checkbox_legalesValido = false;
    }
    habilitarBoton();
}
```

}

And this is the function that activates the register button if everything is ok

```
function habilitarBoton(){
if(nombreValido && apellidoValido && edadValido && mailValido && contraseñaValida && repContraseñaValida && checkbox_legalesValido)
{
    $("#registrarse").removeAttr("disabled").css('background-color', '#fff');;
}else{
    $("#registrarse").attr("disabled", "disabled").css({'background-color' : '#ccc', 'color' : '#000'});
}
```

}

The main problem is the condition for the checkbox, is not working don't know why and my form won't work until I figure out that. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** This is the HTML

```
    <div id="cuadro_izq">
        <form>
            <div class="titulo_loguearse">
                LOGUEARSE
            </div>
            <div id="form_loguearse">
                 <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex1" class="loguin_label">Mail:</label>
                    <INPUT type="text" NAME="mail" id="tex1" class="loguin_field"><br />
                 </div>
                 <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex2" class="loguin_label">Contraseña:</label>
                    <INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="contrasena" id="tex2" class="loguin_field">
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div id="boton_loguin">
                <input type="submit" value="Entrar" id="entrar" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="cuadro_der">
        <form>
            <div class="titulo_loguearse">
                REGISTRARSE
            </div>
            <div id="form_registro">
                <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex3" class="loguin_label">Nombre:</label>
                    <INPUT type="text" NAME="nombre" id="nombre" class="registro_field"><br />
                    <div id="caja_req_reg_nom">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex4" class="loguin_label">Apellido:</label>
                    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="apellido" id="apellido" class="registro_field"><br />
                    <div id="caja_req_reg_ape">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex5" class="loguin_label">Edad:</label>
                    <INPUT type="text" NAME="edad" id="edad" class="registro_field"><br />
                    <div id="caja_req_reg_edad">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex6" class="loguin_label">Mail:</label>
                    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="mail" id="mail" class="registro_field"><br />
                    <div id="caja_req_reg_mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex7" class="loguin_label">Contraseña:</label>
                    <INPUT type="password" NAME="contraseña" id="contraseña" class="registro_field"><br />
                    <div id="caja_req_reg_pass">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="renglon">
                    <label for="tex8" class="loguin_label">Repetir contraseña:</label>
                    <INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="repetir_contraseña" id="repetir_contraseña" class="registro_field"><br />
                    <div id="caja_req_reg_repass">
                        <!--<p class="texto_req_reg">Texto prueba</p>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="renglon" id="renglon_legales">
                    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="aceptar_legal" id="checkbox_legales">
                    <label for="tex9" id="legales_label">Acepto las disposiciones legales</label><br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="boton_registrarse">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" id="registrarse" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html

Comment: where is `textoEnP()` called?

Comment: textoEnP() is called in the document.ready like this $(".registro_field").keyup(textoEnP);

Comment: Which jquery version u r using?

Comment: Should'nt you call `textoEnP()` for each form element ?

Comment: That's what is doing, every time I click on a field `textoEnP()` is called

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($("#checkbox_legales").prop(":checked"))
```

More info

http://christierney.com/2011/05/06/understanding-jquery-1-6s-dom-attribute-and-properties/

Answer (score 0):

```
idInput2
```

only matches 1 `case` so all other conditions are not reached.
So if you call the function once, only one of your validations gets true and if you call it for every validation you might want to move the call to `habilitarBoton()` out of that function

Comment: That's one problem, `habilitarBoton()` is not being called so the validation won't happen. Where should I call that function?

Comment: i think you shouldn't use `switch-case` here. use `if(<FieldValue> == ""){`... for all your validations.